# How to repair damaged Android 4.2.2 on tablet?

Tags: factory-reset, 4.2-jelly-bean

While deleting apps to free up storage, I removed important system
functions (display touchscreenscanning).
How can I replace the system with a fresh version of Android 4.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a complete ROM for your tablet and flash it. Basically:
1. Search Google for " stock ROM" if you want the exact same system. Make sure you get the "gapps" (Google Apps) for that version of Android.
2. You will need a custom recovery, so search Google for " custom recovery" (TWRP and CWM are 2 common recoveries).
3. Find the instructions to flash your tablet

Comment: OP specified he wants to "replace the system with a complete new Android v4.2.2", so I believe he means "repair" instead of "upgrade" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have a fully-functioning device again, you should be able to do a factory reset to return to a factory image. If you did not root, then your system image should be ok.

Navigate to *Settings > Backup and Reset > Factory data reset* and proceed from there. **This will delete all data on the device**, but your installation of Android 4.2.2 will be fresh, just when you started using it.